# How does one append a unix timestamp on a filename which is inside an argument?

Tags: shell, date

To be more specific, I want the Unix timestamp to be appended to my file name:

```
db:backup --database=mysql --destination=s3 --destinationPath=date+random.sql --compression=gzip
```

However, this gives me "date+random.sql" as the filename, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 7):

Use the `$( ... )` construct to create a textual output of a command `...` substituted; as in...

```
--destinationPath="$(date)"+random.sql
```

But note that the standard date format is not well suited for timestamps, so you'd typically define a more appropriate format, as in..

```
--destinationPath=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)+random.sql
```

Comment: Please disregard my answer if it still appears. The above is correct. see http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html

Comment: $(date +%s) provides a Unix time timestamp. This is my favorite for archiving purposes.

Comment: I think the OP tried to use `+` as a concatenation operator, but did not actually intend to get it inside the file name :)

Comment: @John; I suppose so, but having some separator is not bad, I'd say. I also suspect that the OP does not need a literal string "random", but actually something like `--destinationPath=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)_$RANDOM.sql`. (He surely found that out himself. :)

Comment: That doesn't fully work for cron jobs on Ubuntu, had to append \ to escape

Answer (score 1):

I also like 
    --destinationPath=$(date +%F)+random.sql

which gives a date like `2015-03-17`.

I believe the date formats are [Posix formats](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) used in strftime().